# how to show images in pop up by clicking on any particular image

Tags: angularjs, image, ionic-framework, popup

I have one grid view layout. I need to show pop up , when ever user press any image. That particular image should be show as pop up.

My code that display grid view images :

```
<div ng-repeat="eventimgs in MediaURL">

    <div class="row"  ng-if="$even">

        <div class="col col-50"><img ng-src="{{MediaURL[$index]}}" style="width: 100%;height: 217px;object-fit: cover;" /></div>

        <div class="col col-50"><img ng-src="{{MediaURL[$index + 1]}}"style="width: 100%;height: 217px;object-fit: cover;"/></div>
    </div>

</div>
```

Comment: Use UI Bootstrap modal. When click on image, you can pass the image ID and show. https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#/modal

Comment: @Manikandan  i am new to ionic. By onclick function i dont know how to pass the id of the seelcted image and to show the pop up

Comment: This may helpful https://devdactic.com/images-videos-fullscreen-ionic/

Comment: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/CEjIf ,       https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/service/$ionicPopup/

Comment: Use This Plugin : https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/photo-viewer

Answer (score 3):

you can refer the below links,

http://lokeshdhakar.com/projects/lightbox2/

http://www.w3schools.com/jquerymobile/tryit.asp?filename=tryjqmob_popup_image

Comment: first link is broken